# Nginx - how to set up projects with root in different directories

Tags: nginx

I'm just starting to learn about web development and server administration and I have a simple nginx web server setup on a Raspberry Pi. Right now, my server serves files only from one directory, `/srv/http/nginx`.

What I would like to be able to do is set it up so that a url like `pi.local/blog` goes to `/srv/http/pelican/output` and another url like `pi.local/something.html` goes to the original directory.

I know that I should be using `location` blocks in my nginx config, but I can't seem to get them to work. What I have right now is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    index index index.html index.php;

    location / {
        root /srv/http/nginx;
    }

    location /blog {
        root /srv/http/pelican/output;
    }
}
```

But, when I go to `pi.local/blog`, I get errors like `/srv/http/pelican/output/blog no such file or directory`. I think I understand why this is happening, but what is the correct way to create the behaviour I described?

Comment: You should use `alias` in this case

Comment: Thanks! This looks like it's just what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to rewrite an URL, because without rewriting the web-server will indeed look for a `blog` in a document root directory:

`location /blog {
     rewrite ^/blog(.*)$ /$1;
     root /srv/http/pelican/output;
 }`